# (MATLAB) How can I copy certain multiple elements from certain rows of a matrix based upon the values of other elements in those rows?

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

So, I have large matrix (let's say dimensions are 160x6 and the name of the matrix is datamatrix). Next, let's say I have another matrix called datamatrix2 which has dimensions 80x2. Here's what I want to do:

- find every row of datamatrix where the value in column 2 is 2 and the value in column 5 is 1,
- and then take the value for column 3 and the value from column 6 of each of those rows and place them in column 1 and column 2, respectively, of datamatrix2.

So, for example:

Let's say that row 3 of datamatrix is the first row in datamatrix with a 2 in column 2 and a 1 in column 5. Let's say there is a 3.096 in column 3 of that row and a 10 in column 6 of that row. So, 3.096 would be placed in position 1,1 of data matrix2 and 10 would be placed in position 1,2 of datamatrix2.

Next, let's say that row 25 of datamatrix is the next row in datamatrix with a 2 in column 2 and a 1 in column 5. Let's say there is a 16.432 in column 3 of that row and a 15 in column 6 of that row. So, 16.432 would be placed in position 2,1 of data matrix2 and 15 would be placed in position 2,2 of datamatrix2.

This process would continue until all of the rows of datamatrix with a 2 in column 2 and a 1 in column 5 have been found.

Please let me know if anyone has any suggestions.

Mucho thanks!

G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I follow your explanation rightly, what you want is:

```
index = (datamatrix(:,2) == 2) & (datamatrix(:,5) == 1);
datamatrix2 = datamatrix(index,[4,6]);
```

This solution uses logical indexing.`index` stores 1's and 0's depending on wheter the condition is fullfilled or not.

To start of with logical indexing it is easiest to start with a vector. Lets take `x = [2 5 3 4 6];` and you want the first, second and fifth entry. Then `x([1 2 5]) = [2 5 6];` This can also be expressed logically with `x(logical([1 1 0 0 1])) = [ 2 5 6];` Notice how we have a `true` at every position we want.

The same can be applied when we want to access a matrix.
Lets take  `A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]` as a sample matrix. The obvious way to access part of this matrix is something like `A([1,2],[1,3]) = [1 3; 4 6]`. We can now replace the index with a logical notation:

`A([1,2],[1,3]) = A(logical([1 1 0]),logical([1 0 1])) = [1 3; 4 6]`.

Logical and vector notation can also be combined. In my code `index` is a logical representation of the columns we want, `[4 6]` is the vector notation of the rows we want. Therefore the right columns and rows will be selected.

Comment: This worked, thank you! Can you please explain the second line of your code; I don't completely understand it.

Comment: Edited my answer to explain logical indexing a bit. If you have further questions please let me know!

Comment: Wonderful. So very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what exactly you are trying, but lets take a shot

First: find any value (here 6) in any column (here 2) and then take another value of the found rows from any column (here 5) (here with an example `magic`-matrix)

```
datamatrix = [magic(5) magic(5)];
myvalue = 2;
values = datamatrix(find(datamatrix(:,2)==myvalue), 5);
```

If you have 2 conditions for a row, then use this here

```
values = datamatrix(find((datamatrix(:,column1)==value1).*(datamatrix(:,column2)==value2)),column3);
```

if you need to get more than one value, say from two different columns, then you just need to replace `column3`with something like this

```
column3 --> [col1 col2 col3]
```

Summarizing, try this code here

```
values = datamatrix(find((datamatrix(:,2)==2).*(datamatrix(:,5)==1)),[3 6]);
datamatrix2(:,[1 2]) = values
```

The second statement may fail because of dimension errors. If so, you should maybe provide the datamatrix entries.

Comment: I would use logical indexing here, so `(datamatrix(:,column1)==value1)&(datamatrix(:,column2)==value2)` instead of `find((datamatrix(:,column1)==value1).*(datamatrix(:,column2)==value2))`